# Java: Transforming List<List> into a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

Given a list of unique-valued sublists (that is to say two different sublists cannot share elements of the same value) - eg:

`List[List[1, 1, 1], List[2], List[4, 4], List[7]]`

how would this be transformed into a Map with a (value, size) key-value pairing?

This would result in:

```
{
  1 : 3
  2 : 1
  4 : 2
  7 : 1
}
```

Defining our List as `values`, I would assume that one could use streams and collect as a Map as such:

`values.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, ? ));`

Currently unsure what to put in for the second parameter as it requires a `value mapper` but does not allow for `.size()` to be called upon any of the sublists.

Comment: What is the expected output when the input is `List[List[1, 1, 1, 6], List[2], List[4, 4], List[7, 6]]`? Is it expected to be `{1:4,2:1,4:2,7:2}` or would it be `{1:3,2:1,4:2,6:2,7:1}`?

Comment: @Naman we're assuming that the input consists only of Lists with elements of equal value within their respective List. `List[1, 1, 1, 6]` does not fit this description.

Comment: Alright, then consider the input `List[List[1, 1, 1], List[2], List[4, 4], List[7], List[1, 1]`, what do you expect as an output now?

Comment: You raise good edge cases - I'll update my question to note uniqueness between elements from any two sublists not including itself.

Answer (score 7):

When using `Collectors.toMap`, you need to specify how to get the key and the value from each element of the stream.  `Integer::intValue` won't work here, because your stream elements are lists, not integers.

For the key, get the first element of the list.  (This assumes that the inner lists are all non-empty.)  For the value, pass the `size` method reference.

```
values.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(list -> list.get(0), List::size));
```

Comment: Based on another answer, what becomes unclear is the [expected output for a different input.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088052/java-transforming-listlist-into-a-map#comment102574823_58088052). Might be worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten the list and then use something like Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()).
However in this case i would say a good old (nested) for loop might be simpler to write and read.

```
List<List<Integer>> lst = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,1,1),Arrays.asList(2),Arrays.asList(4,4),Arrays.asList(7));

Map<Integer,Integer> result= new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
System.out.println(lst);
//[[1, 1, 1], [2], [4, 4], [7]]

for(List<Integer> sub:lst){
  for(int n:sub){
    Integer last=result.get(n);
    int newCount=(last==null?0:last)+1;
    result.put(n, newCount);
  }
}
System.out.println(result);
//{1=3, 2=1, 4=2, 7=1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [@rgettman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088127/507738) is the most elegant. However, it makes the presumption that all lists are non-empty. Of course this is easily fixed by simply adding `.filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())` before the `collect` reduction operation.

This is another approach, which no longer considers the list to be 'two-dimensional', that is, `List<List<Integer>>`, but instead flattens it to just a stream of `Integer`s.

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = lists.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: It really matters what is the expected output when the input is `List[List[1, 1, 1, 6], List[2], List[4, 4], List[7, 6]]`. The output upon such case would differ in the two answers.

Comment: This yields, indeed, a whole different result. At the moment, all posted answers suffer from such an anomaly.